# Using Apigee with PHP

Tags: php, apigee, usergrid

We heard about UserGrid as a NOSQL non-relational database and a highly scalable solution for a project. We were positive that this was the route for us, until we found Apigee. Apigee seems to be based on UserGrid but offers hosting as well as other useful functionality like push notifications (very useful).

We had a look at the PHP SDK on GitHub - this is not available in the Apigee admin panel under available SDKs. Are we correct to think that we can use this PHP SDK with Apigee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it's missing - and it looks like there is at least one broken link to the SDK as well. But absolutely - the SDK for Usergrid is here and should for you: https://github.com/apache/incubator-usergrid/tree/master/sdks/php

Scott

Answer (score 0):

As Scott says, the php SDK that is at Apache should be fully compatible with Apigee's API BaaS.  However, it has not been vetted by Apigee and included in an official release. If you find any issues, please bring them up here on stack overflow and we will do our best to address them ASAP.

Also, the developer who collaborated with me on the Usergrid PHP SDK has released the next revision of it, located here:  https://github.com/ossobuffo/usergrid

He is submitting it to Apache now.

Comment: Thanks rockerston, will be sure to report any issues